# Dynamic routing, extra query params get added to URL, Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, parameters, nextjs-dynamic-routing

For some reason every time I access this url `/someCategoryName/someSlugName` I get redirected to `/someCategoryName/someSlugName?category=someCategoryName&slug=someSlugName`. Same with `/popular/someSlugName` to `/popular/someSlugName?slug=someSlugName`

I am using Next.js 13 with `pages` folder, Vercel, React. I have dynamic pages with following routes: `[category]/[slug].tsx` and `popular/[slug].tsx`
I have getStaticPaths and getStaticProps on this page.
Everything seems to work fine, but for some reason every time I access this url `/someCategoryName/someSlugName` I get redirected to `/someCategoryName/someSlugName?category=someCategoryName&slug=someSlugName`. Same with `/popular/someSlugName` to `/popular/someSlugName?slug=someSlugName`

What could be the problem? I don't have this kind of redirects in my code, or any pushes from useRouter, so I have no idea why these query params appear...
Has anybody ever encountered simmiliar issue?

I have also rewriting logic in my middleware, to be able to serve different page folders for different domains, but still, there is no logic between those appending query params and my rewrites.